# Open new terminal and run command there, and come back to original terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a test case in Python, which checks if license server is up or not.

In the script, there is a command to open up server, but the next command terminates the server.

Therefore, I would like to open new terminal, and run license server there, and come back and run the next command.

I would like to keep both terminals.

Please provide such methods to accomplish this in Python.

```
command = "some command to start up license server"
hi = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate()[0]

if serverup() is None:
   raise Exception("NOOOOOOOOOOOO")
```

My code looks like this, and raises exception at if statement, because server gets terminated.

Comment: `subprocess` or `os.system` might be what you're looking for. It's difficult to tell without knowing more specifics about your code

Comment: Already using subprocess.

Comment: I am confused. Is your server localhost or some external server? You shouldn't need to keep terminal to access computational resources. Most commands can be run on background detached with `nohup`. If you need to check health of server port, just send some message over to the port.

Comment: Looks like one of my directory was misnamed....